# Node Red send IP to Telegram BOT

Tags: telegram-bot, node-red

I really need help since I do not understand how to solve this problem.

I want to be able request my public ip with the help of Node Red and Telegram.
I want to send /ip in my Telegram Bot and then I would like to get the response back to the same channel.

As you can see on the picture I use an IP function that fetch my IP:

```
2022-07-19 22:29:2 9node: debug 1
msg.payload : Object
{ 
   internalIPv4: "192.168.1.244", 
   internalIPv6: undefined, 
   publicIPv4: "XXX.XXX.XXX.XX"
}
```

But my Telegram Sender only give me

```
2022-07-19 22:29:29node: 0cc0a76d4b287f23
msg : string[25]
"msg.payload.type is empty"
```

How do I solve this issue. I want to get my IP as the message reply. Does any one know how to solve this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed that I needed to insert a function after IP.

```
var mess = msg.payload.publicIPv4;

msg.payload = {
    chatId: 'XXXXXXX',
    type: 'message',
    content: mess
}

return msg;
```